# Unable to create dataframe from RDD of Row using case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 2.x, it seems I cannot create a Dataframe using a RDD of Row composed of case classes.

It did work fine on Spark 1.6.x but fails on 2.x the following runtime exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timestamp is not a valid external type for schema of struct<seconds:bigint,nanos:int>
```

preceded by a bunch of generated code from Catalyst.

Here is the snippet (simplified version of what I am doing):

```
package main

import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, LongType, StructField, StructType}

object Test {

  case class Timestamp(seconds: Long, nanos: Int)

  val TIMESTAMP_TYPE = StructType(List(
    StructField("seconds", LongType, false),
    StructField("nanos", IntegerType, false)
  ))

  val SCHEMA = StructType(List(
    StructField("created_at", TIMESTAMP_TYPE, true)
  ))

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

    val rowRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((0L, 0))).map {
      case (seconds: Long, nanos: Int) => {
        Row(Timestamp(seconds, nanos))
      }
    }

    spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, SCHEMA).show(1)
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this is a Spark bug or something I missed in the documentation (I know Spark 2.x introduced runtime Row encoding validation, maybe this is related)

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if it is a bug or not but mixing dynamically typed `Row`, case classes and explicit schema doesn't make much sense. Either use `Rows` and schema:

```
import collection.mutable._
import collection.JavaConverters._

spark.createDataFrame(ArrayBuffer(Row(Row(0L, 0))).asJava, SCHEMA)
```

or case classes:

```
import spark.implicits._

Seq(Tuple1(Timestamp(0L, 0))).toDF("created_at")
```

Otherwise you're just doing the same job twice.

**Note**:

If you want express that fields can be nullable you use `Options`. For example

```
case class Record(created_at: Option[Timestamp])
case class Timestamp(seconds: Long, nanos: Option[Int])

Seq(Record(Some(Timestamp(0L, Some(0))))).toDF
```

will generate schema where `created_at` and `created_at.milliseconds` can be `NULL`, but `created_at.seconds` has to be set if `created_at`  is not `NULL`.

Comment: I am required to use explicit schema as I am working with pre-existing parquet schema which has specific set of fields nullable and others non nullable which I can't control explicitly using case classes (to my knowledge). I didn't know about Row of Row tho, will try this out. Thanks

Comment: You actually can express nullability with case classes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I went with the Row of Row without case classes even tho I understand this is not the most ideal solution but since the underlying parquet schema has a weird composition of nullable and non nullable, I find it easier to reason about using explicit schema. Thanks again.